# VB.NET sum using whileloop

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, sum

I have managed to write code that sums values, but only if I know how many values the user want to sum from the beginning (using array).

Here is my code that works fine, if the user first enters the number of values he/she wants to sum:

```
Public Class WholeNumbersForAdd
    Private numberOfVal As Integer
    Private sum As Integer
Private Sub NumbOfVal()
        Console.Write("Numbers of values to sum? ")
        numberOfVal = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub enterVal()
        Dim nums(numberOfVal) As Integer


        For i As Integer = 1 To numberOfVal Step 1
            Console.Write("Please give the value no " & i & " (whole number): ")
            nums(i) = CInt(Console.ReadLine)
        Next 
        For Each value As Integer In nums
            sum = sum + value
        Next

    End Sub
```

Now, I am trying to make changes that sum an undetermined number of values using a while-loop but I can't seem to get a grip of the While-loop, that I must use in this exercise. I want the program to keep taking in new values (one value per row) until the user presses the Q-button. When the user press Q, I want the program to sum all values that the user had entered.

Here is what I got so far, but I know that I am faaaaaar away from a solution.

```
    Private Sub enterVal()

    Dim nums As Double
    Dim inputValue As Double
    Dim sumValues As Double

    While (inputValue <> Q)
        Console.Write("Write an amount to sum or press Q to finish: ")
        nums(inputValues) = CDbl(Console.ReadLine)

    End While

    For Each value As Integer In inputValue
        sumValues = sumValues + value
    Next

End Sub
```

Btw. I am not allowed to use "Do Loop While".

Comment: What do you mean _not allowed to use "Do Loop While"_, is this a homework question?

Comment: Use a `List` instead of an array, and `Add` each new input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are entering value through `Console.ReadLine` so your `While (inputValue <> Q)` will never work properly

```
While True
    Console.Write("Write an amount to sum or press Q to finish: ")
    Dim inputString as String = Console.ReadLine
    If inputString.ToUpper = "Q" Then Exit While
    nums(inputValues) = CDbl(inputString)
End While
```

You do not need a value in While, loop indefinitely, hence `While True`
Take the input into a string, because you are expecting Q, which cannot be a number as it was in your example.
Check if you entered q or Q (remove `.ToUpper` if you don't need to check for lower case q) and exit the loop if it is.

The general design is not a good one, but I left it in in case that's part of your assignment.

**NOTE:** The code above is not tested

Comment: Thank you @George, I used most part of your code, had to make small adjustments. I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim m, n, c, d As Int16

        Dim first(,) As Int16 = New Int16(5, 5) {} 
        Dim second(,) As Int16 = New Int16(5, 5) {} 
        Dim sum(,) As Int16 = New Int16(5, 5) {}

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix")

        m = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())

        n = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the elements of first matrix\n")

        c = 0
        While c < m
            d = 0
            While d < n

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Element [" + c.ToString() + " , " + d.ToString() + "]") 
                first(c, d) = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
                d = d + 1

            End While
            c = c + 1 
        End While 
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements of second matrix") 
        c = 0
        While c < m
            d = 0
            While d < n 
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Element [" + c.ToString() + " , " + d.ToString() + "]") 
                second(c, d) = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()) 
                d = d + 1 
            End While
            c = c + 1
        End While

        c = 0
        While c < m
            d = 0
            While d < n
                 sum(c, d) = first(c, d) + second(c, d)
                 d = d + 1
             End While
            c = c + 1
        End While
         Console.WriteLine("Sum of entered matrices:-")
         c = 0
        While c < m
            d = 0
            While d < n
                 Console.Write("  " + sum(c, d).ToString())
                 d = d + 1
             End While
            Console.WriteLine()
            c = c + 1
        End While
         Console.ReadKey()
     End Sub
End module
```